# How can I create my own Xbox 360 theme?

Tags: xbox-360

How can I create my own theme for Xbox 360? Is it relatively straightforward with the use of software (either on the Xbox itself, my PC or a combination of both). Or is there a huge process like when submitting games to the arcade involving approval, assigning points for purchase, etc?

All I want to do is use my own background photo/wallpaper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHPfxDD1Xuo&feature=related) details how to add your own background to the Xbox 360 dashboard.

Essentially:

1. Create an image of the correct dimensions (JPG format only).
2. Put the image onto a portable device, or connect your Xbox to your PC.
3. Navigate to the image you've created via the Xbox .
4. Select the image and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to assign it as your wallpaper.

Hope this benefits someone. Valid as of the Xbox 360 software version being used 14 / Feb / 2012.

Comment: I never knew it was so easy!  I might try it now...

Comment: Wow I had no idea either... new theme coming up soon.